# Help With My Motor Controller Circuit Diagram

Tags: transistors, motor, raspberry-pi, npn

I'm a novice when it comes to electrical engineering, primary since I'm a programmer. However, I am trying to make a drone for fun and I made a really(REALLY) basic motor controller with some NPN transistors and a raspberry pi v2. But I want to make sure that I'm doing everything nicely, but more importantly right.

Please, any feedback on my motor controller and circuit in general will be a great help!

[image]

Comment: You really do not want bipolar transistors for drone motors, but rather logic-level low RDSon NFETs.  Also you probably do not want a AA cells or a raspberry pi, and this project is far more complicated than you imagine.  You will probably find the most practical information on rcgroups.com expect your question here to be closed as a duplicate of a similar previous one.  If you want to do things from a software perspective the best bet may be to reprogram something like an H8mini, CX10, or the little Nuvoton-based Hubsan.

Comment: In that configuration, you'd need a voltage slightly higher than the voltage across the motors to turn them on, if you've got the transistors underneath the motors (they'll only need about 0.7V to turn on then - slightly more than the voltage on the 'emitter' pin) in your schematic and add resistors of a few hunderd ohms on the pins gping to the pi you should be good (the exact resistor value is not too critical provided you've got smallish low power motors)

Comment: At the very least, please move the transistors to the downstream side of your motors (i.e. between the motor and gnd. This allows the transistors to function os "switches" more effectively, and stops them from "voltage limiting" power to the motors as much. Also, as @ChrisStratton mentioned, nFETs will be quite preferrable for this application, as they generally dissipate less power.

Comment: You will want separate power supplies for motors and controller, otherwise noise from the motors will crash the controller. I suggest a LiPo battery (you'll have to decide on capacity and weight) which gives between 3V and 4.2V. Drive motors directly from battery. Add a boost converter to give you 5V for the Pi. You're not the first person to do this, so there are plenty of writeups on the internet to learn from.

Comment: Also, you cannot do open-loop speed control and expect to stay in the air. Quadcopters need some sort of accelerometer/gyro system linked to closed-loop speed control.

Comment: @pjc50 - actually motor speed control is rarely closed loop.  Feedback from at least rate gyros is necessary for stabilization, but the control loop can and usually does directly drive motor "effort" output without the need to consider motor speed.  A boost converter is unnecessary - the poster really should not be using a pi as a flight controller as that points to a larger and more dangerous platform where the pi's unreliability is unacceptable, but a system capable of carrying one would use a multi-cell battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting the motor from the transistor's Emitter to ground is not good because you lose a lot of voltage. Firstly, the Pi only puts out 3.3V. Secondly, the TIP102 is a [Darlington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) transistor which internally has *two* Base-Emitter junctions in series that drop at least 1.2V. Therefore the motor will only get 3.3V - 1.2V = 2.1V. The other 2.9V appears across the Collector-Emitter junction and is wasted.

[image]

For lowest loss you should connect the the motor from V+ to the transistor's Collector, and the Emitter to ground. You should also put a resistor in series with the Base to limit I/O current (a 1kΩ resistor would allow about 2mA through, which is enough to switch 1A). This configuration decouples I/O and Base-Emitter voltages from the output, and also allows you to use a higher voltage motor battery. Collector-Emitter voltage drop is reduced to about 0.8V at 1A.

For even lower loss you could replace the TIP102 with a MOSFET, which can have extremely low Drain-Source resistance, and its Gate doesn't draw any current so output is not limited by I/O drive current (however you *do* need a FET which turns on fully at 3.3V). The [IRLML2502](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1yID244zNAhXC3KYKHcWmDUIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infineon.com%2Fdgdl%2Firlml2502.pdf%3FfileId%3D5546d462533600a401535667f44d2602&usg=AFQjCNEE8aMXIis_kT5f-yBFg4uqFjfjMA&sig2=Ss4NcAhK_JmOHgAo8kECWg) is a popular FET that drops ~0.1V at 2A with 2.5V Gate drive.

To control motor speed you use PWM, which switches the motor on and off rapidly to create a lower average voltage. One problem with this is that the motor's inductance will try to keep the current flowing when switched off, creating a voltage spike that wastes energy and can damage the transistor. A fast switching diode should be wired across the motor to recirculate the current and prevent voltage spikes.

If the I/O pin is floating on power up then the FET may partially turn on and run the motor before your program gains control. to prevent this you can wire a 'pull down' resistor from Gate to ground.

The final circuit looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbKZdV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However the Pi itself may not be a good choice for your application. For good stabilization you need a fast feedback loop with accurate high frequency PWM, but the Pi only has 2 hardware PWM channels. Perhaps you could just run two motors to test your initial code, then port it to a more capable platform for the working drone.

Comment: The irony is that "a more capable platform" for such a task is a simple microcontroller like an ARM Cortex M0, chosen to have four PWM timer channels, and with no operating system scheduler to get in the way.